# Auto discover a web server hosting PHP script

Tags: php, service-discovery

Having a simple PHP script running on a web server in my local network, how can I auto discover this script (or better the server hosting the script) using an external client (e.g., an Android app).

I am aware that this will not be possible with a pure PHP script hosted on a web server. I need to bind a socket to the broadcast address 255.255.255.255 or some multicast address.

Maybe a python script could do, e.g., http://stuvel.eu/blog/186/start-xbmc-from-remote
Apache ZooKeeper seems interesting but too big and complicated at the same time.

What other options are their? Does some of the "big" web servers provide some kind of easy to use service discovery?

Comment: A restful API maybe?

Comment: Please elaborate. I cannot see how concepts REST and API make any sense here.

Comment: Avahi a.k.a. Zeroconf a.k.a. Bonjour. Implementations exist for all major OSes, start reading e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software) Essentially, each server advertises to the local network "I have service X running on port Y", and clients can receive this information automagically. No central configuration required.